# Correct implementation of IGrouping to be used inside longlistselector groupheader

Tags: linq, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have an ObservableCollection like the following-

```
    private ObservableCollection<KeyedList<int, Anime>> _grp;
    public ObservableCollection<KeyedList<int, Anime>> GroupedAnimeByGenre
    {
        get
        {
            return _grp;

        }
        set
        {
            _grp = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("GroupedAnimeByGenre");
        }
    }
```

I am using this to populate a LongListSelector with grouping. The KeyedList is implemented like this-

```
public class KeyedList<TKey, TItem> : List<TItem>
{
    public TKey Key { protected set; get; }

    public KeyedList(TKey key, IEnumerable<TItem> items)
        : base(items)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public KeyedList(IGrouping<TKey, TItem> grouping)
        : base(grouping)
    {
        Key = grouping.Key;
    }
}
```

I have the following code to feed the ObservableCollection. Keep in mind AnimeList2 is a temporary Collection.

```
 var groupFinale = AnimeList2.GroupBy(txt => txt.id).Where(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1).ToObservableCollection();

 GroupedAnimeByGenre = groupFinale ;
```

But I am unable to convert/use groupFinale with GroupedAnimeByGenre. I am missing the extension method part as I am not well aware of the syntax. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `ToObservableCollection()` call and take just that part

```
var groupFinale = AnimeList2.GroupBy(txt => txt.id).Where(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1);
```

you'll see that the type of `groupFinale` is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Anime>>`. Hence applying `ToObservableCollection()` will result in `ObservableCollection<IGrouping<int, Anime>>`. However, the type of the `GroupedAnimeByGenre` is `ObservableCollection<KeyedList<int, Anime>>`. So you need to convert `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Anime>>` to `IEnumerable<KeyedList<int, Anime>>` which in LINQ is performed by the [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) method.

Shortly, you can use something like this

```
var groupFinale = AnimeList2
    .GroupBy(txt => txt.id)
    .Where(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1)
    .Select(grouping => new KeyedList<int, Anime>(grouping))
    .ToObservableCollection();
```

You can make such conversion easier by providing an extension method (similar to BCL provided `ToArray()` / `ToList()`) that will allow skipping the type arguments like this

```
public static class KeyedList
{
    public static KeyedList<TKey, TItem> ToKeyedList<TKey, TItem>(this IGrouping<TKey, TItem> source)
    {
        return new KeyedList<TKey, TItem>(source); 
    }
}
```

Then you can use simply

```
var groupFinale = AnimeList2
    .GroupBy(txt => txt.id)
    .Where(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1)
    .Select(grouping => grouping.ToKeyedList())
    .ToObservableCollection();
```